# What is the difference between proc{} and &proc{}

Tags: ruby, closures

What is difference in below usage

```
a = proc { puts 'hii' }

def abc(&a)
  a.call
end
abc(&a)

def xyz(c)
  c.call
end
xyz(a)
```

In below implementation more than one blocks can be passed as arguments -

```
def pqr(c, &t)
  c.call
  yield
  xyz(c)
  abc(&t)
end   
pqr(a) { puts 'block to method'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first of the two, the `&a` parameter will also capture a block passed like this:

```
abc {puts "Hello world"}
```

This is the same as:

```
xyz(proc {puts "Hello world"})
```

The other of the two only allows the last of the two.

Comment: Above both is not same in first case `actual block is passed` to method and in second case `block is passed as argument`. Second one should raise `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`